# How I Can Send An Array to WebService Method

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, android-asynctask, webmethod

i need to send a multiple values to a webservice -asp.net- via android application

this is the webservice method

```
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function AddTheNums(ByVal nums() As String,) As String

            For i = 0 To nums.Length - 1

--some process

            Next

        Return status
    End Function
```

and i use this code to in android

```
public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    public Login(String MethodName)
    {

    }   
    public void onPreExecute() 
  {

  }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
         final SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);             
         request.addProperty("nums", params[0]);
         request.addProperty("nums", params[1]);
         final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         envelope.dotNet = true;
         try 
            {
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                    
                    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();          
                    response = result.toString();
            }

    return response;

    }
@Override
    public void onPostExecute(String res)
{
}

}
```

can any one help me on this i need to send a multiple nums to the parameter in webserive

i used this code

```
     request.addProperty("nums", params[0]);
     request.addProperty("nums", params[1]);
```

but it doesnt work correctly ...

Best Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize an array of ints to send using KSOAP2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951333/serialize-an-array-of-ints-to-send-using-ksoap2)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure that it's possible to use multiple params with same name in soapobject. Isn't it better to pass param like
request.addProperty("nums", params);
And I suppose this discussion can help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ksoap2-android/pq1V2ZXY3D8