# ksoap2 Set String[] to request.addProperty

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2, ksoap

When I use String[] a for add property in SoapSerializationEnvelope ,return error

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_SendArray);       

              //Use this to add parameters
              String[] a ={"21","22","23","66"};
              long[] x= new long[] { };
              request.addProperty("NumberList",a);
              request.addProperty("ID",x);

              //Declare the version of the SOAP request
              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              envelope.dotNet = true;
```

---

```
request body :

SendArray{NumberList=[Ljava.lang.String;@4052fa20; ID=[J@4052fb28; }

Error :

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: [Ljava.lang.String;@4052fa20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be possible..

Try this link :) It is helpful to me too.

[Serialize an array of ints to send using KSOAP2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951333/serialize-an-array-of-ints-to-send-using-ksoap2)

Answer (score 1):

Type `String[]` isn't serializable in term of ksoap library.
See [this link](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives) for information about sending arrays of data.